# Django Errors in terminal

Tags: django, terminal

I'm running Django 2.17 and I get many many errors from the dev server, the terminal prints this error 5 or six times on every requestx to the dev server.

Trying to add --verbosity 0 to the runserver command does not supress them.

I want to print from functions in views, but I don't need the errors from django.

Someone on the django IRC channel told me that they were normal... but it looks as if something is not configured correctly to me.

EDITED IN:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
   self.finish_response()
  File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
  File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
self.send_headers()
  File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
self.send_preamble()
  File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "c:\python\Lib\socketserver.py", line 796, in write
self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\Lib\socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\python\Lib\socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\python\Lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\python\Lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\python\Lib\socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
self.handle()
  File "c:\python\Lib\socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
self.handle()
  File "C:\Python\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 151, in handle
self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 153, in handle
self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 176, in handle_one_request
handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Python\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 176, in handle_one_request
handler.run(self.server.get_app())
 File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
self.close()
 File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
self.close()
 File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
  File "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What's above the line "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"?

Comment: I added the first traceback error, but it looks like the code from the dev server is causing this "c:\python\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35

Comment: This is a python bug, will be fixed in version 3.7.4. See more [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9713)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to split a variable that you expect to be `str` but which is somehow `NoneType` (`None`) instead.

Comment: True - but it's the simple_server.py file thats doing it.